# PostgreSQL: Update multiple rows in table with a single query

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-update, where-clause

Suppose I have a table `Car`. This table has the following columns: `id`(uuid), `status`(text), `color`(text).

I have pushed all the `Car` ids that have a specific color into an array:

Suppose I have an array of the `Car` ids (the size of the array can change):

```
let car_ids_arr = ['id1', 'id2', ...'idn']
```

Now I need to update all rows (for example, set `status` to `false`) in `Car` where the id matches the ids in `arr`. I don't want to do this in a for loop and make several calls to the database, I rather do it all in one call.

The size of my array of ids can change , so I am not sure how to approach this... any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easily done with array operator `any()`:

```
update car
set status = false
where id = any(array[1, 2, 3])
```

If `id` actually is of `uuid` datatype:

```
update car
set status = false
where id = any(array[...]::uuid[])
```

Comment: I am getting an error when issuing this query: 
```ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = text
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.```

Comment: @kris: you did not mention that we were dealing with `uuid`s. Then follow the error hint and do cast. See my updated answer.

Comment: Also, what if I want to use my array variable `car_ids_arr` in the query instead of `array[...]`?